# TinyMCE - preview format

Tags: tinymce

I added the following formats:

```
  style_formats : [
    {title : 'Text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#000000'}},
    {title : 'Bold Text', inline : 'b'},
    {title : 'Blue Text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#6289AF'}},
    {title : 'Blue Header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#6289AF'}},
    {title : 'Orange Text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#FF8612'}},
    {title : 'Orange Header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#FF8612'}}
  ],
```

How can I make these menu option to display as preview (e.g actually bold or colored)?

adding the following did not help:

```
preview_styles: true,
```

nor

```
preview_styles: 'font-size font-weight color',
```

relevant link: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=71853